# Running .py file with docker in folder structure

Tags: python, docker

I'm new to docker and I just build my first docker image with the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ .
COPY data/ .

CMD ["python", "./src/project/hello.py"]
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error: `python: can't open file './src/project/hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

The project has the following structure:

```
├── data
|   |-- file1
|   |-- file2
├── src
|   |--project
|   |   |--hello.py
├── Dockerfile
├── requirements.txt
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the file layout inside your container?  (If you `docker run --rm -it yourimage sh` you will get an interactive shell inside the built image to look.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `WORKDIR` setting in your Dockerfile.

> The WORKDIR command is used to define the working directory of a
> Docker container at any given time. The command is specified in the
> Dockerfile.
>
> Any RUN, CMD, ADD, COPY, or ENTRYPOINT command will be executed in the
> specified working directory.

Point the `WORKDIR` argument in your Dockerfile to the right location and it should work without errors.

Reference: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-workdir-command-in-docker